# PostgreSQL equivalent of MySQL --force flag

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I am doing bulk inserts of 10000 records into Postgres:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES (v1),...,(v10000)
```

I am doing this via the Python Psycopg2 library. Currently, if one of the tuples, say number 5000 bombs (for example if a field is of the wrong type), my entire batch insert fails because an exception is generated. I am looking for the equivalent of MySQLs --force flag which solves exactly this problem; which tells MySQL to keep going on any errors (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_force)

I do not see anything here, and this is for an even newer of PG, which is quite worrisome: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-select.html

Comment: What does it bomb on?

Comment: For example "value X is too big for "smallint"". I just want to not insert all rows that violate some kind of data insertion error and keep going. Because I do not know all of the possible data errors ahead of time, I would much rather not implement this logic to check the tuples before trying to insert...what a nightmare that would be.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Postgres' transaction handling is stricter than MySQL's. Postgres does not support transactions where only some of the statements can be committed because it violates the "atomic" concept of a transaction. The only way something like this could be done is using single inserts with savepoints for each insert. But that will be very slow.

Answer (score 1):

Tell psycopg you want it to use a transaction isolation level of "autocommit", i.e., it will not open a transaction for you and each statement will be automatically committed. Note that you'll have to catch exceptions and ignore (or better, log) them. Example:

```
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extensions

conn = psycopg2.connect("...")
conn.set_isolation_level(ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)
curs = conn.cursor()

for row in your_data:
    try:
        curs.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES (%s, %s, ...)", row)
    except Exception, err:
        print err

 # no need to commit!
```

Comment: The bulk insert is part of a transaction that must be rolled back if sometething else in the transaction fails; does this affect that?

Comment: Definitely. You can't do "autocommit" *inside* a transaction, sorry. If I were you I'd simply reorder the SQL: fill the bulk table using autocommit; start a transaction and if it fails just remove rows/drop the bulk table.

Answer (score 0):

do this in psql `\set ON_ERROR_ROLLBACK on` and try it again

Comment: Do I execute this first as part of the transaction? I am interacting via Psycopg2 as mentioned, not the native psql CLI.

Comment: Yeah this doesn't help me then. Unless some how I can set this thing forever.

Comment: well. it IS a  run-time configuration parameter so I imagine it can be set in postgresql.conf.